# How to get unique count by month for different categories in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, pivot

I have a pandas data frame like this:

```
Month      ID
Sep 21     ID_1
Sep 21     ID_2
Sep 21     ID_3
Oct 21     ID_1
Oct 21     ID_2
Oct 21     ID_4
Oct 21     ID_5
Nov 21     ID_1
Nov 21     ID_2
Nov 21     ID_3
Nov 21     ID_4
Dec 21     ID_2
Dec 21     ID_3
Dec 21     ID_4
Dec 21     ID_5
Jan 22     ID_3
Jan 22     ID_4
Jan 22     ID_5
```

and i want ID counts in a format like this as the output pandas dataframe:

[image]

where as values i can get unique count of IDs for each month like ID1 in October 2 should be counted under 2 months as it is appearing for 2 months now and in Nov ID2 will be counted under 3 month as it is consistently appearing for 3 months. But as ID5 appears first time in Oct it will be counted under 1 month in Oct and so on. Any ID which appears more than 4 times should be counted under 4 month+ category.

In pandas i am not sure how to go about this approach to get this unique count and have a pivot table.

Comment: `df.Month.unique()`

Comment: This will just give me the unique values of the month column

Comment: What else do you require?

Comment: What do the month-id's represent? I'm not sure how a single month (sep) can contain multiple 'months' (eg, 2 Month, 4 Month+).

Comment: IDs are a separate column not for months. They are member IDs. By 2 month, 4 month+ i mean how many times an ID have appeared. As Sep is first month here so for this month values for 2,3 and 4 + month would be zero. I have updated the result table to indicate how i want IDs to be calculated and how the result should look like.

Comment: With each progressing month the repeating IDs will get old. Like here ID2 will be counted under 4 month category in Dec as it is appearing for 4 months consecutively.

Comment: Will you please provide your input dataframe as text?

Comment: I have added it as text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, this will create a matrix of occurence. Note that I used date-time format for `Month` for easy-sorting.

```
step1 = pd.crosstab(
    df['ID'], 
    pd.to_datetime(df['Month'], format='%b %y')
)

Month   2021-09-01  2021-10-01  2021-11-01  2021-12-01  2022-01-01
ID                  
ID_1    1   1   1   0   0
ID_2    1   1   1   1   0
ID_3    1   0   1   1   1
ID_4    0   1   1   1   1
ID_5    0   1   0   1   1
```

Then, do the cumulative sum that satisfy the continuity condition

```
for month_prev, month_next in zip(step1.columns, step1.columns[1:]):
    step1[month_next] = (step1[month_next] + step1[month_prev]) * step1[month_next]

Month   2021-09-01  2021-10-01  2021-11-01  2021-12-01  2022-01-01
ID                  
ID_1    1   2   3   0   0
ID_2    1   2   3   4   0
ID_3    1   0   1   2   3
ID_4    0   1   2   3   4
ID_5    0   1   0   1   2
```

Then, we apply `melt`, `groupby`, `value_counts` to count those cumsum-values  for each month, `unstack` to move `Month` to the columns, and the rest 3 methods to take care of formatting.

```
step2 = pd.melt(step1)\
    .groupby('Month')['value']\
    .value_counts()\
    .unstack(level=0)\
    .fillna(0)\
    .drop(0)\
    .astype(int)

Month   2021-09-01  2021-10-01  2021-11-01  2021-12-01  2022-01-01
value                   
1   3   2   1   1   0
2   0   2   1   1   1
3   0   0   2   1   1
4   0   0   0   1   1
```

Last step for further formattings:

```
step2.columns = step2.columns.strftime('%b %y')
step2.loc[4] = step2.loc[step2.index>=4].sum()
step2.index = (step2.index.astype(str) + ' Month').str.replace('4 Month', '4 Month+')

Month   Sep 21  Oct 21  Nov 21  Dec 21  Jan 22
value                   
1 Month 3   2   1   1   0
2 Month 0   2   1   1   1
3 Month 0   0   2   1   1
4 Month+    0   0   0   1   1
```